# How to run Vue directive on page load?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm looping over an array of objects consisting of map `svg paths` and `locales` and want to run a function upon load. The function has to take the `locale keys` of the `paths` array as parameter and do something with it:

```
<p v-for="(country, locale) in paths" @load="myFunction(locale)">log {{locale}}</p>
```

but `@load` does nothing. The same code works with the `@click` directive:

```
<p v-for="(country, locale) in paths" @click="myFunction(locale)">log {{locale}}</p>
```

This is the function:

```
const myFunction = (locale) => {
    console.log(locale)
}
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Why dont you load it from `created` or `mounted` hook?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: why would you like to load a function on the rendering? could you provide more context? i am sure there is a better solution then that

Comment: I have to loop over an array to build an svg world map and color the countries, which are `svg paths`. They are built inside a `v-for` loop. It would be most convenient if I could incorporate my function into the `v-for`, while the html is being built

Answer (score 1):

```
<p v-for="(country, locale) in paths">log {{myFunction(locale)}}</p>

methods: {
    myFunction(locale) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

It's resolve your question?

Comment: No, I need to run the function inside the `dom element`, not inside the `display slot`. The `<p>` is just an example. I need to run the function inside a `svg path` while iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like directives are the wrong tools for the job. you seem to have all related variables in one array anyway, so why not iterate through the array in `mounted`? eg:

```
mounted() {
  this.paths.forEach((path) => {
    this.myFunction(path.locale);
  })
}
```

this could also be done in the `created` hook

Btw: You are not using directives here, @click and @load are just events and you register listeners to it. the element fires click on click but doesnt fire the load event, thats why it doesnt trigger your function. maybe you misunderstood what a directive is

Comment: Speaking of mounted: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/computed-vs-methods-vs-mounted-vs-created/35230 Might be useful.